# How to set value back from the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a page withthe following in loop

```
<i
  ng-click="showRed=true"
  ng-show="!showRed"
></i>
<i
  ng-class="red"
  ng-show="showRed"
  ng-click="delete($index)"
  ng-mouseleave="setTimer(showRed)"
></i>
```

... and in the controller

```
$scope.startTimer = function(confirmRemove) {
     $scope.deleteTimerHandle = $timeout(function() {
       $scope[confirmRemove]=false;
  }, 1000);
}
```

What it should do (I've simplified the code above a lot) - I have a trashcan font-awesome icon, which when clicked hides and instead another icon (delete cross, with red CSS class) is shown and when clicked, it start the delete function.

What I need to do is to keep the second (red) icon displayed until I either:

- click it (which calls my delete function and redraws the page afterwards)

or

- I move the mouse out of the icon and it brings the first icon back after certain number of seconds

**My question is**: How do I change the variable set in ng-onclick in the controller?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: You need to create a directive and listen for the `click` and`mouseleave` events then change the state